# Duplicating, expanding, and assigning a new group if some condition is fulfilled for the group

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to expand a group if it contains rows with "Check" in the Class column.
In other words, to replicate the non-"Check" rows in the same group and assign the newly created rows as its own group if necessary.

Original dataframe:

```
test <- data.frame(value = 1:9, 
                     group = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C"), 
                     Class = c("Text", "Text", "Text", "Check", "Check", "Check", "Text", "Text", "Check"))
```

Desired result:

```
desired <- data.frame(value = c(1,2,3,4,7,3,5,7,3,6,7,8,9), 
                   group = c("A", "A", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_2", "B_2", "B_2","B3", "B3", "B3", "C", "C"), 
                   Class = c("Text", "Text", "Text", "Check","Text", "Text", "Check","Text", "Text", "Check", "Text", "Text", "Check"))
```

A dplyr answer, if possible (but any answers welcome).

I did get to here, which produces almost the desired result:

```
test %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(row_number = case_when(Class == "Check" | !any(Class == "Check") ~ 1, 
                                any(Class == "Check") ~ sum(Class == "Check"), 
                                TRUE ~ NA)) %>% 
  uncount(row_number, .id = "id")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R option using `expand.grid` + `rle`

```
test[
    unlist(
        lapply(
            split(cbind(id = 1:nrow(test), test), ~ factor(group, levels = unique(group))),
            \(d) {
                r <- with(d, rle(Class))
                l <- r$lengths
                if ("Check" %in% r$values) {
                    c(t(expand.grid(split(d$id, rep(seq_along(l), l)))))
                } else {
                    d$id
                }
            }
        )
    ),
]
```

which gives

```
    value group Class
1       1     A  Text
2       2     A  Text
3       3     B  Text
4       4     B Check
7       7     B  Text
3.1     3     B  Text
5       5     B Check
7.1     7     B  Text
3.2     3     B  Text
6       6     B Check
7.2     7     B  Text
8       8     C  Text
9       9     C Check
```

---

Sorry for my poor `dplyr` skills, but maybe you can try improve it from my attempt

```
test %>%
    mutate(id = seq_len(n())) %>%
    summarise(idx = {
        r <- rle(Class)
        l <- r$lengths
        if ("Check" %in% r$values) {
            list(c(t(expand.grid(split(id, rep(seq_along(l), l))))))
        } else {
            list(id)
        }
    }, .by = group) %>%
    {
        slice(test, unlist((.)$idx))
    }
```

Comment: Hmm - does this option let you classify by the new groups? Is there a dplyr option? (Thank you for your answer!)

Comment: @JoLo yes, see my update (but I don't think my `dplyr` skill is proficient)